# Outputting lists as columns

Tags: python, list

I have 3 large lists I want outputted as columns, [0][0][0] and then down. My current written code (that worked for smaller lists) is this:

```
f=open("Clustered_energies.txt", "w")
for i in range(0, len(frame_position)):
print >> f, frame_position[i],energy[i],cell_volume[i]
f.close()
```

That gives me a list index out of range error. I'm guessing I need to use a list comprehension and I tried this:

```
print [(i,e,c) for i in frame_position for e in energy for c in cell_volume]
```

But the output from that repeats a value from each list over and over, is a list comprehension the way to go? Or can my original code be fixed?

Comment: I'd say that one of your lists is smaller than `len(frame_position)`. Ensure that all 3 list lengths match, or use the smallest in the `for` loop and accept that some (end) entries will be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
[[x,y,z] for x,y,z in zip(frame_position,energy,cell_volume)]
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, but if you want to fix the initial solution (maybe functional constructs are not your jam) you can do: `for i in range(0, min(len(frame_position), len(energy), len(cell_volume)))`.

Comment: This is good and what I was aiming for but how can I get the output back into columns?

Comment: Each list in the returned list of lists is a column:

`col1,col2,col3 = [[x,y,z] for x,y,z in zip(frame_position,energy,cell_volume)]`

Comment: Yeah I see but it looks like [1, -142.430591, 350.42033525], [14, -140.575693, 353.514272], [17, -140.52751, 353.754234] whereas before it looked like 1 142.430591 350.42033525 with the other values below

Comment: If you just want to print the values you can do: `for x,y,z in zip(frame_position,energy,cell_volume): print x, y, z`

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) but it stops at the shortest list and so I would use [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (it is called [`zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python3 for future reference):

```
import itertools
for i, e, c in itertools.izip_longest(frame_position, energy, cell_volume, fillvalue=" "):
    print i, e, c
```

Comment: +1. That's correct, if the desired behavior is to have 
"default values" this is the way to go.